# Get song name and artist from iTunes top 100 by Python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler, itunes-store

I am kinda new to Python Crawl and wanted to get the songs and artists only. Scrapy would definitely do this easier but I wanted to try with requests and bs4.

I knew I need to get data from here: https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=100/json

The data looks quite complicated to me, I would appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction.

Best,

Answer (score 1):

You don't really want to use beautiful soup, because you have json data.
You just need requests.

```py
import requests

url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=100/json'

response = requests.get(url)

data = response.json()

for artist_dict in data['feed']['entry']:
    artist_name = artist_dict['im:artist']['label']
    song_artist = artist_dict['title']['label']
    print(artist_name)
```

Comment: Where did you find the URL? It's not documented anywhere but it works